# Creating a fixed header

Tags: html, css, header

I'm trying to create a website based on [THIS DESIGN](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SmoothTransitionsResponsiveLayout/).
it's tutorial can be found [HERE](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/12/css-only-responsive-layout-with-smooth-transitions/)

I want to create a fixed header which will contain the username and password text InputBoxes or the username if the user is already logged in.
I tried to do it the usual way using the following CSS.

```
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
```

but somehow the header doesn't display at all. 
How do I have a header that is fixed and remains there no matter how many divisions i scroll through in above design?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a height to the header?

Comment: Do you have some content in header or not? If not, please add height to it.

Comment: @vineetrok Show us your html too.

Comment: try to add a fiddle of what you've tried.

Comment: @techfoobar yes, I did that, but , the header is not showing up atall.

Comment: @kalpeshpatel the entire code is same as its here: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SmoothTransitionsResponsiveLayout/

Comment: I think element with class .st-container is overlapping the header, try setting z-index

Comment: @kalpeshpatel Thanks! dont know how i missed that. it works now.

Comment: @vineetrok No worries, sometimes it happens that we miss simple things. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's how you can do it:**

1. Either set the **height** of the fixed-header or populate it with **content** so it isn't empty
2. Set a high **z-index** so it doesn't get overlapped by #st-container

CSS:

```
height: 50px
z-index: 999
```

Here's the **jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ncQGc/